# angularjs definitely typed visual studio 2015

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2015, typescript1.5, definitelytyped

I'm trying to get my first angularjs project to work within Visual Studio 2015. Worked fine until I tried to move to Typescript. Installed the DefinitelyTyped projects and get lots of error messages.

**Here is how to reproduce it:**

- Create an empty ASP.NET 4.5.2 application
- Nuget AngularJS Core 1.4.4
- Nuget AngularJS.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped 4.1.1 (includes jQuery 0.0.1)
- Add an empty TypeScript file
- Add

  ```
  /// <reference path="typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />
  ```

  to that file.
- that's when I get 444 errors, starting with

  ```
  Error   TS2411  Property 'find' of type '{ (selector: string): 
  IAugmentedJQuery; (element: any): IAugmentedJQuery; (obj: JQuery): 
  IAugment...' is not assignable to string index type 'HTMLElement'.  
  TypeScript Virtual Projects l:\M\eigene dateien\visual studio 
  2015\Projects\WebApplication3\WebApplication3\Scripts\typings
  \angularjs\angular.d.ts
  ```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong or how to work around it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I checked this package and most of the errors seem to come from the jquery.d.ts file, which just looks old. That file still uses "bool" instead of "boolean", which was a breaking change made long ago.

I fixed it by adding "jQuery.Typescript.DefinitelyTyped" to the project, which upgraded the jQuery.d.ts file to a version that parsed properly. As soon as I did that, all of the compiler errors went away.

This seems like a bug in the nuget package authoring. I'll look into opening an issue on github.

Hope that works for you.

UPDATE: I opened this issue in GitHub https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/issues/5446

Comment: Awesome! Works fine now.  
**I should say that I had to add the jQuery.Typescript.DefinitelyTyped before the Angular one.**  
I had been wondering about the 0.0.1 version number of the jQuery DefinitelyTyped, but there are so many things to wonder about when starting with Angular...
Anyway, thanks a lot. Now working with Angular is even more fun.

Comment: I had the same issue for this, just upgrade it.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, but the above solution didn't work out for me.
jQuery.Typescript.DefinitelyTyped was already installed as it is required by angularjs.TypeScript.DefinetlyTyped package.

I fixed it by:

1. uninstall angularjs package.
2. uninstall angularjs.TypeScript.DefinetlyTyped package.
3. uninstall jQuery.Typescript.DefinitelyTyped
4. install jQuery.Typescript.DefinitelyTyped
5. install angularjs.TypeScript.DefinetlyTyped package.
6. install angularjs package.

Thanks Michael for supplying the hint.

Comment: Did you try to update it? As Angularjs Type Script install it but the old version.However, you solution is working :)

Comment: you must update it to the latest version, for some reason nuget was installing version 0.0.1 and it is on 2.8.8, when visual studio auto-grabs typescript definitions it doesn't seem to always grab the latest, or correct one.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is caused by NuGet in VS 2015, because it defaults to installing the oldest version of its dependencies which in this case installs ancient jQuery DT package for the AngularJS DT package, as explained [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/5446#issuecomment-133750608).

I fixed this even simpler by just doing these:

1. Manage NuGet packages for project
2. Show only installed packages
3. Select jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped
4. Upgrade
5. Enjoy!