# Where is the Angular's definitions file so I can reference it in my VS2015 ASP.NET 5 project?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, visual-studio-2015

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088619/angularjs-definitely-typed-visual-studio-2015) SO question is suitable for ASP.Net 4.5. I'm after ASP.Net 5.

After downloding *angularjs.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped* from NuGet, I want to add a .ts file to my project with a reference to angular's definitions file, that is a reference using

`/// <reference path="???/angular.d.ts"/>`

but I don't know what to write in the '???' section of it ...

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

> but I don't know what to write in the '???' section of it

Recommend you use `tsconfig.json` instead of reference tags in new projects. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json

Comment: I'm already using .tsconfig, but 'angular' is not recognized by the compiler. That's why I need to reference it somehow..

Comment: Add `angular.d.ts` to the `files` list